# vimscript: how to get selected text in a register in normal mode?

Tags: normal-mode

I am trying to get the mouse selected text in a register in normal mode. If the selection is a substring, only the selection should be copied, not the complete word.

Currently the script has:

`normal! "zyiw`

I would use the script on remote servers without X too. vim is compiled without clipboard.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the mouse selection is in the * register (assuming your vim is built with the right support). what else would you want?

Comment: I am trying:

```
@z = @*

but z doesn't have the text. How can I confirm if my vim has the support for this?

Comment: Which feature should I look for in my `:version` output?

Comment: I believe it's the feature `+clipboard`.

Comment: I have the default version on Ubuntu without clipboard (`-clipboard`). Is there any other way to do this?

I am trying a modify a script to highlight multiple mouse selected text (even substrings) with different colors. Currently it matches the complete word under cursor.

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean visual selection via mouse.  If so you would just use `normal! gv"zy` (mouse has no bearing on this, it's just visual selection).

Comment: I am trying to modify it that way:
`visual selection - gv"zy` and if not `"zyiw`. Now how do I clear the visual buffer after the text is copied to "z so I can use the technique next time?

Answer (score 1):

Selection of text via the mouse (in a plain vanilla vim, no vimrc, no plugins, etc) places the selection in the "* register.

A subsequent assignment,

```
:let @f = @*
```

will place the text into the f register. A mapping such as

```
:map ^va :let @f = @*^v^M
```

will copy the "* register to the *f register using ^a (control-a). additional configuration will permit using <C-a> and <CR> in place of ^va and ^vM.

Perhaps the simplest way, however, is to select the text with the mouse or one of the "V" commands (V, v, CTL-v) and then enter in normal mode

```
"gy
```

This will "yank" the current selection into the "Y register.

Comment: That requires vim to be compiled with `+clipboard`.

Comment: If there is not text selected, I am trying to get the current word under the cursor.

Comment: In .vimrc I have - `:map ^va :let @f = @*^v^M`
I have the following in the plugin:
`:if @f == "" normal! "zyiw :else :let @z = @f :let @f = "" :endif`
but it's always the word under cursor that I get in z.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the visual buffer? The I can select in visual mode, copy to z and clear the visual buffer again (as well as z after use).

Comment: you can use the :let @<buffer name> = syntax to set it to anything you want.  just curious - why would you want to clear it?

Comment: If I don't clear it the variable retains the data from previous visual copy.

Comment: are you using the real control-v or are you typing <caret>v?

Comment: is having something in the "* register a problem?  what is the overall effect you're trying to accomplish.  it really isn't necessary to clear the register as it'll get overwritten the next time you copy something to it.  why is having something in the register a problem?

Comment: if you have a standard distribution such as ubuntu, you can prob'ly use the <c-x> notation.  :map <c-a> :let @f = "*  you're checking +clipboard using :ver, right?  seems like the standard ubuntu full version would be compiled with it (i use a ubuntu derivative - mint).  do you have the large full vim installed or the minimal vim?  does using the mouse to select actually put stuff into "*?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did finally:

In vim I have:

```
:map <C-a> :normal! gv"zy<CR>
```

And in the script I added:

```
:if @z == ""                                                                                                                            
    normal! "zyiw                                                                                                                       
:endif
...
// do something
...
:let @z = ""
```

In general, a visual selection followed by 1. Esc and 2. ^a will be highlighted.

If there is no visual selection, the word under cursor will be highlighted.

The complete script is [here](https://gist.github.com/jarun/0d89dc61598118926ed82947e88610b3).